# Is it possible to make an Android app that blocks other apps (using Flutter)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Can we do an app that blocks other apps which we wanted ? (Using Flutter)

Comment: What dou you mean by "block" other apps?

Comment: like lock them a certain time

Comment: Your are saying like Parental control ?

Comment: yes like parental

Comment: Well for that using flutter wont be the best option. You need to go to native environment because you can do more things that you cant do using flutter. And you need to find resources yourself because building parental control  is not easy as it sounds you need every single bit of permission from user and from google end too when you upload your app to play store in future.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. Using anything

Comment: There are applications which do exactly this, and there are other entries in StackOverflow as well, where a lot of possible ways are mentioned.